# How to handle special characters in ODATA query

Tags: odata, power-automate

I have data which has the parameter "{IsFolder}" **with** curly brackets. I need to filter based on that parameter with ODATA. How can I achieve that?

"IsFolder" does not exist and passing {} fails as well. I could not find a simple table of conversion anywhere.

EDIT:
Data source is a power automate flow where it lists all entities in sharepoint (properties only). I need to filter out evertyhing that is not a folder in order to get only the files for processing. Part of the data (i've removed most of the values due to data privacy):

```
"@odata.etag": "\"11\"",
"ItemInternalId": "60",
"ID": 60,
"Modified": "2023-11-22T13:20:30Z",
"Editor": 
"OData__DisplayName": 
"{Identifier}": 
"{IsFolder}": false,
"{Thumbnail}":
```

My goal is to improve processing time. I already have a "filter array" action that does the trick when it comes to filtering out the folders, I just wanted to have it filtered out at the origin so that I can focus on other filtering needed for the processing.

New EDIT: ODATA doesn't enjoy special characters. Blank spaces in column names must be replaced by `_x0020_` for example. I need this same type of conversion for {}

Comment: Can you update your question with a snip of the action and OData query? What's the data source?

Comment: @SamNseir I've edited it, see if it's better now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems `{IsFolder}` is not allowed in the filter query. There isn't any offical documentation on this apart from maybe [SharePoint -Delegation notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepointonline/#delegation-notes) stating that it is not delegable. This is just an assumption on my part.

See if this alternative filter does the trick: `FSObjType eq 0`

Comment: The property name is the issue, yes. Because it will fail if I use {IsFolder}: The $filter expression "{IsFolder} eq 'false'" is not valid. Creating query failed

But I tried your suggestion either way:
The $filter expression "{IsFolder} ne 1" is not valid. Creating query failed.

Comment: Updated answer - apologies, normally I would test and validate, however I don't have access to test currently.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work: The $filter expression "%u007BIsFolder%u007D eq 'false'" is not valid. Creating query failed (tried with ne 1 as well and failed with the same error)

Comment: Updated answer again.

Comment: Thanks! `FSObjType eq 0` did the trick. I've added a filter post ODATA to check if any "IsFolder" true passed the filtering in the original data, and it returned empty. Thanks a lot!! And thanks for the delegation notes, it'll be useful for the rest of the actions I need to work on